# Can I still join a Clan after starting my own?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I created a clan ready for when I go into clan wars however one thing I want to do is just see in person how they play out. The idea is so I can merge my Clash of Clans clan with my forum so I can award members for their exploits, but ofcause I need to see what kinds of awards I should create.

So I am wondering, can I still join a clan after starting my own?

Comment: Can't be in two clans at the same time. You can leave the one you made and join another though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. But you'll have to leave your own clan to join another clan. Remember: once you create your own clan, you can't delete or rename it, but you can leave it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only be in one clan at once. You can leave the clan you made in order to join a  new one.